# routerLink Working fine on Chrome but not on firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this line of code in my html , it is working fine on chrome but not on any other browser (tested on firefox and IE)

```
<button class="btn btn-link"><a routerLink="/ga-report/microsite-averages">Microsite Averages</a></button>
```

> Using Angular 4.4.3

Comment: `a` inside `button` ? what kind of html is that?

Comment: Yes it is not good practice , but it works only on chrome @YoukouleleY

Comment: is there a particular reason for this weird construct? if not the answer is: either use `a` or `button` but not both at the same time

Comment: ok thanks @YoukouleleY

Comment: You really should simply be using an <a>. This is a navigation link, why use a <button>? The link can be styled as a `btn` with Bootstrap classes with effectively no issues.

Answer (score 0):

It was my silly mistake, Never use Button and a together. Both have differnet behaviour so may be here chrome play smart role but not other browser .

> Change it to this and works fine

```
<button class="btn btn-link" routerLink="/ga-report/microsite-averages">Microsite Averages</button>
```